# How to run shell built in command like ( source, history) using chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to run shell built in command like ( source , history ) in my chef recipe but its not getting executed and also there is no debug message.

I have tried the below, but not successful.

```
#script 'run_full_bldsys' do
#  interpreter "csh"
#  code <<-EOH
#  source /etc/config.main
#  cd /idb/software/compile/
#  bldsys -f -R </dev/null> & bldsys.log &
#  EOH
#end
#
#

#csh 'run_full_bldsys' do
#  code <<-EOH
#  source /etc/config.main
#  cd /idb/software/compile/
#  bldsys -f -R </dev/null> & bldsys.log &
#  EOH
#end
```

Please help.

Comment: Is the comments character (`#`) really intended (if so, it's obvious it won't execute comments) ? If not, be respectful of helpers on StackOverflow and post real code....

Answer (score 0):

Using the `script` or `bash` (or if you really mean to be using csh, then `csh`) resource is correct. Remember that the `source` directive will only affect things later in that same script and will have no impact on Chef itself or other processes launched by Chef.